# Error de sintaxis al crear procedimiento almacenado

Tags: sql, sql-server

estoy creando un procedimiento almacenado para listar cosas productos etc pero al crearla me sale un error en select indicando que esta a la espera de external

```
iF EXISTS (SELECT NAME FROM sys.procedures WHERE NAME = 'ListarGenero')
  Begin 
       Print 'El Procedimiento ListarGenero >>Ya Existe<<'
  End
ELSE
  Begin 
      Create Procedure ListarGenero as select *from Genero order by IdGenero asc
      Print 'La tabla Genero Fue Creada'
  End
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola. Por favor, edita tu pregunta y añade la etiqueta del motor de BD que estás usando

Comment: SQL Server 2014 Management Studio

Comment: Gracias. PD. El Management Studio es el cliente que se conecta a la BD, la BD se llama SQL Server 2014, a secas ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes un bloque anidado y no te va a dejar crear el procedimiento así nada más.

¿Cómo anidado? Pues es que el BEGIN..END es un bloque de transacción y la creación del procedimiento es otro.

Así pues, la solución es que uses SQL dinámico para crear el procedimiento:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT NAME FROM sys.procedures WHERE NAME = 'ListarGenero')
    Begin 
        Print 'El Procedimiento ListarGenero >>Ya Existe<<'
    End
ELSE
    Begin 
        DECLARE @sp_sql varchar(255);
        SET @sp_sql = N'Create Procedure ListarGenero as select * from Genero order by IdGenero asc';
        EXEC(@sp_sql);
        Print 'La tabla Genero Fue Creada'
    End
```

Con todo y el espacio que faltaba en `*from`. Luego ejecutas la sentencia con `EXEC(@sp_sql)`.